Blender tool add ons
Does Blenders user licence allow for a user to integrate external tools to work the program into use in the construction industry,such as making add on tools

Yes, you can create addons as well as modify the open source code.

You'll find more informations here. Basically you can do almost anything you want to Blender. https://www.blender.org/support/faq/
